# Connect to nearest agent in collection

Tags: java, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

So I have several different agent types: Person, Factory, Hospital, Home, Doctor.
Now, all of these agents except Person are connected through a network, while the initial population size of Person = 0.

Now, when the model runs, Person agents will be generated with a given rate. What I want to accomplish is that each instance of Person determines which instance of Factory, Hospital or Home is the nearest, and then makes a connection to that particular agent.

How would I accomplish this?

I have so far been able to let instances of Person connect to the nearest Hospital, the nearest Factory, or the nearest Home. I wrote the following code in the entry action box in a Person's statechart:

```
Hospital nearestHospital = this.getNearestAgent(main.Hospital); this.connectTo(nearestHospital);
```

But I have been unable to let the instances of Person determine the nearest instance of Hospital, Factory, Home concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Person agent you have to create 3 link to agents as you can see in the following figure: You will find them in the Agent palette.

[image: Person Agent]

After that, you have to create connections independently for hospital, home and factory. (since they are different agents)

```
Hospital nearestHospital = this.getNearestAgent(main.hospitals);
Home nearestHome = this.getNearestAgent(main.homes);
Factory nearestFactory = this.getNearestAgent(main.factories);
double distanceToHospital=distanceTo(nearestHospital);
double distanceToHome=distanceTo(nearestHome);
double distanceToFactory=distanceTo(nearestFactory);

hospitalLink.disconnectFromAll();
homeLink.disconnectFromAll();
factoryLink.disconnectFromAll();

if(distanceToHospital<distanceToHome && distanceToHospital<distanceToFactory)
   hospitalLink.connectTo(neareastHospital);
else if(distanceToHome < distanceToFactory)
   homeLink.connectTo(neareastHome);
else
   factoryLink.connectTo(nearestFactory);
```

That's the way it must be done... what you do later with it... I don't know

Comment: Thank you, Felipe. However, this is not what I meant. I want the person agent to consider hospital, factory and home concurrently and connect to the nearest one, so that person is connected to only one of hospital, factory and home.

Comment: How would I modify this if I would like to find out what the second nearest instance of Hospital is? So I have first defined the nearestHospital, and now I'd like to know the second nearest agent. So far my search has not found a clearcut solution to this problem.

Comment: Something like this

List <Hospital> hospitalList=sortAscending( hospitals, h -> h.distanceTo(yourAgent) );  

Hospital nearest=hospitalList.get(0);  

Hospital secondNearest=hospitalList.get(1);